# How can I add a user interrupt to an infinite loop?

Tags: ruby, interrupt, infinite-loop, interrupt-handling

I have a ruby script below which infinitely prints numbers from 1 onward. How can I make the script stop its infinite execution through an interrupt in the terminal like 'Ctrl+C' or key 'q'?

```
a = 0
while( a )
  puts a
  a += 1
  # the code should quit if an interrupt of a character is given
end
```

Through every iteration, no user input should be asked.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't print from 1 onward. It prints from 0 onward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have to check the exit condition in a separate thread:

```
# check for exit condition
Thread.new do
  loop do
    exit if gets.chomp == 'q'
  end
end

a = 0
loop do
  a += 1
  puts a
  sleep 1
end
```

BTW, you will have to enter `q<Enter>` to exit, as that's how standard input works.

Comment: Thanks Mladen..!!. Its just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 15):

Use Kernel.trap to install a signal handler for Ctrl-C:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

exit_requested = false
Kernel.trap( "INT" ) { exit_requested = true }

while !exit_requested
  print "Still running...\n"
  sleep 1
end
print "Exit was requested by user\n"
```

Comment: Hi Peter!! thanks for your answer, but this was not exactly what I was looking for.