# Ruby - Function keys listener with Interruptions

Tags: ruby, interrupt, keylistener

I would like to add some listeners on F1..F4 keys for example in order to make a loop program interactive with users....
For exemple: exiting some `while` loops, entering some `if` loops or printing some messages...

My searches on that subject routed me to [Curses module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607891/ruby-curses-how-to-get-ctrl-meta-keys-with) But the [documentation here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/curses/rdoc/classes/Curses.html) is quite poor, and I can't make it work... And I found [`Kernel.trap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508764/how-to-add-a-user-defined-interrupt-to-an-infinitely-running-ruby-program) but it only trap some inside events and I would like to add some listeners to create other events.

I didn't find any gems or gits which could help me to do that. Is it possible to do it with ruby? What's the best/versatile way?